# Flutter Web - How to hide the scrollbar in ListView?

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, flutter-web

In Flutter web, there is a visible scroll bar in `ListView` and `SingleChildScrollView` by default.

How to hide it?

Comment: physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: Disabling the scroll hides the scrollbar but not a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`ScrollConfiguration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html) widget to pass a spesific scroll behaviour to the widget tree.

```
ScrollConfiguration(
    behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
    child: ListView(...)
)
```